# Fecho fermoso y otras f más

Tags: ortografía, pronunciación, historia

Esta es una pregunta sobre fonética en el castellano antiguo. Leyendo el Quijote se puede ver que "hacer" se escribía "facer" antiguamente, al igual que muchas otras "h" se escibían como "f", esto mismo lo he podido leer en otros libros más.

> mucho agravio me habedes fecho en despedirme y reprocharme con el riguroso afincamiento de mandarme no parecer ante la vuestra fermosura

En algún momento se empezó a cambiar esa f por h, pero, fue un cambio solo de grafía o fue un cambio realemente fonético? Quiero decir, la gente decía "facer" o decía "hacer" y escribía facer?

Comment: Generalmente los cambios fonéticos anteceden a los cambios ortográficos.  El cambio ortográfico es la aceptación de que el cambio fonético tuvo lugar.  Esto no quiere decir que el cambio sea homogéneo, creo que hasta no hace mucho aun en algunas regiones aisladas era común pronunciar _/facer/_ en el hablar común o en algunas frases hechas, aunque la escolaridad y los medios masivos probablemente reduzcan cada vez más estos arcaísmos.

Comment: Simplemente por añadir a las respuestas que ya se han dado. En asturiano (bable), por ejemplo, aún existen muchas palabras (derivadas en su momento de las grafías y pronunciaciones con |f|) que se escriben y pronuncian con dicha letra. P.Ej: Pero fíu, ¿qué tas faciendo?

Comment: Aunque la pregunta no lo implica directamente, me gustaría aclarar que en época de Cervantes no se hablaba así. Don Quijote usa el habla medieval propia de los caballeros andantes, no la habitual de su tiempo. Por eso mucha gente se queda confundida al escucharle.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Es una pregunta muy interesante, aunque parece ser que no existe una respuesta clara al respecto...

Te aconsejo leer este [**completo artículo en Wikipedia**](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cambio_fon%C3%A9tico_%C2%ABf_%E2%86%92_h%C2%BB_del_espa%C3%B1ol), que trata exclusivamente sobre este tema, donde se explican las diversas teorías que exiten actualmente sobre las causas de este fenómeno.

Según este artículo, una de las teorías más ampliamente aceptadas es la de [Ramón Menéndez Pidal](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ram%C3%B3n_Men%C3%A9ndez_Pidal) que atribuye el fenómeno al **substrato vasco-cántabro-ibérico**:

> [...] *los vascos y los cántabros (y
>   presumiblemente también los íberos), cuyas lenguas carecían del sonido*
>   **/f/**, la iban sustituyendo por una aspiración en **/h/** *que,
>   acústicamente, era el sonido más cercano.* [...]

Desafortunadamente, parece que ser que existen numerosas objeciones a esta teoría, y las conclusiones de ese mismo artículo no son demasiado satisfactorias:

> "*Los investigadores* [...] *trataron de explicar el cambio con
>   una sola y sencilla causa, cuando, en ocasiones, un solo factor no es
>   el único responsable de un cambio lingüístico, sino que el proceso
>   puede ser más complejo.*
>   [...]
>   *En resumen, se puede decir que nadie ha analizado satisfactoriamente
>   la complejidad del fenómeno* [...] *aunque se han realizado recientemente y 
>   siguen realizando nuevas invesigaciones al respecto* [...].

Comment: Muchas graciás por el artículo, es muy bueno y me ha sorprendido mucho que la pregunta fuera en realidad tan compleja. Sinceramente pensaba que este tema iba ser más sencillo. Esto explica también la pronunciación algo peculiar que tenemos los andaluces de la h.

Comment: @Rafa, si te digo la verdad yo tampoco tenía ni idea :). Como nota adicional, en gallego seguimos manteniendo la **f** en muchas palabras, como **facer** (*=hacer*), **fermoso** (*=hermoso*), **fame** (*=hambre*), etc...

Comment: Si ni los propios lingüistas se ponen de acuerdo, no seré quien, pero parece la más adecuada.
Añado referencia a [wikipedia del sustrato vasco](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sustrato_vasco_en_lenguas_romances)
Entre el periodo que se hallaba la peninsula antes y durante la reconquista y que sus lenguas vecinas si mantienen la /f/; la única influencia parece la de las lenguas habladas en el Reino de Navarra que estaba en su apogeo. Este reino llegaba hasta el actual pirineo catalàn, basta con ver los nombres de algunas poblaciones cuyo origen es vasco.

Comment: Añado en castellano hierro, hambre > en catalán ferro, fam en portugués ferro, fome en bable ferro, fame en francés fer, faim.

Answer (score 9):

No soy estudioso del idioma, y el artículo citado de Wikipedia es bastante informativo. Pero, la sola experiencia de leer poesía española antigua (no mucho, siglo XVI) me ha mostrado que no fue solamente "un cambio solo de grafía", sino que la antigua "h" (escrita como "f") no era muda (que el sonido fuera el mismo que la "f" actual es otro asunto).

Por ejemplo, toma esta estrofa de [San Juan de la Cruz](http://users.ipfw.edu/jehle/poesia/canticoe.htm) (1542-1591), con la grafía actual:

```
Mil gracias derramando,
pasó por estos sotos con presura,
y yéndolos mirando,
con sola su figura
vestidos los dejó de hermosura.
```

En algunas versiones modernas, el último verso lo escriben: 
*vestidos los dejó de **su** hermosura*. 
En realidad, el original es el anterior, pero con la pronunciación actual esta segunda versión "corregida" suena mejor (mide 11 sílabas), mientras que en el primero es muy fuerte la tendencia a la 
[sinalefa](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinalefa) (pronunciar "de hermosura" como "dermosura") con lo cual
el verso mediría mal (10 sílabas). Este inconveniente desaparece si pronunciamos "hermosura" como "fermosura" (o alguna variante de "h" sonora).

Hay muchos otros ejemplos.

Answer (score 1):

Hay una versión probablemente incorrecta, pero graciosa, que nos argumentaba un profesor ¡de la universidad! como si fuera cierta:

El agua de la meseta castellana es muy rica en minerales, lo que trajo algunas consecuencias penosas como los cálculos renales y la caída de los dientes.

La F no se podía pronunciar sin los dientes incisivos...

Aquí van otros:

farina ----> harina

falcón ----> halcón

fumo   ----> humo

fierro ----> hierro

fungo  ----> hongo

folga  ----> huelga  (viene de "fuelle", tiene que ver con soplar)

fata ----> hada

foja ----> hoja

filio ----> hijo

defensa ----> dehesa

Answer (score 1):

No está claro que pasó pero sí, antes se pronunciaban como efes y en algún momento se fueron haciendo suaves hasta confundirlas con la h aspirada y finalmente desapareció. Una forma sencilla de ver que sí se pronunciaban de esa manera es comparando las palabras con el portugués o el italiano:

Español: Hijo

Portugués: Filho

Italiano: Figlio

Y así como ese hay muchos otros ejemplos.

Comment: La comparación de idiomas es un excelente argumento.

Answer (score -1):

El uso de `fazer` es medieval.  Derivado del latín.

En portugués, aún se usa la F.  No sé porque, pero el portugués se considera latín **vulgar**

Según esta fuente

http://www.sjsu.edu/faculty/watkins/spport.htm

el español castellano se desarrolló cerca de los que vivían en el país vasco. Esa lengua no tiene nada que hacer con latín ni ninguna lengua del mundo.  Esa lengua no lleva el fricativo `f` y por eso, los habitantes de Castilla empezaron a remover el sonido fricativo para comunicarse mejor con sus vecinos vascos.

Comment: Esta respuesta no añade nada a la respuesta seleccionada.